# Why are PHP namespaces not used that often?

Tags: php, namespaces

I have been reading O'Reilly's Modern PHP and it starts with the explanation of importance of the namespace. This left me wondering why have I never seen anyone use namespace in any scripts that I see on GitHub, etc.

Comment: Namespaces _are_ used, not sure why you claim otherwise. But anyway this is a question that cannot clearly be answered, since answers would be primarily opinion based. Such question is considered off-topic here. Please read about what question to ask here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces **are** used most of the time! I don't remember the last time I saw a recent project that wasn't using them.

Take a look on packagist and you'll see that pretty much all of the packages on there use namespaces too.